# Multiple scoring parameters not working with gridsearch

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do a GridsearchCV, but want to use multiple scoring paramaters. It worked fine when I used only one. I used the documentation from sklearn, including this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_multi_metric_evaluation.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-model-selection-plot-multi-metric-evaluation-py). This suggested this should work, I also tried with a dictionary instead of list.

```
scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision']
gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
gs.fit(text, goal)
```

But I get this error and I don't understand why.

ValueError: scoring value should either be a callable, string or None. ['accuracy', 'precision'] was passed

[Full stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxSBI.png)

Comment: This feature is available in version 0.19 and higher. Which version of scikit are you using?

Comment: 0.19.1 so that should no be the problem. Python 3 btw, so also shouldn't be the issue...

Comment: This error is not present in `0.19.1`. Are you sure its `0.19.1`? Are you using any virtual environments? Post the full stack trace of error. Please post the output of `import sklearn; print("Scikit-Learn", sklearn.__version__)` from where you are running the above script.

Comment: It outputs: Scikit-Learn 0.19.1
Using jupyter lab btw.

Comment: I've edited the main post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the import. The import you are using has been deprecated and does not support what you want to do.

Currently you are doing this:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
```

When you do this, you must get a warning about:

> DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in
>   favor of the model_selection module ... ... ...  This module will be removed in 0.20.

Pay attention to that warning, And do this instead:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
```

You can confirm this in the examples you linked. The import is different there.

Answer (score -2):

You need to loop over scoring:

```
scoring = ['accuracy', 'precision']
for score in scoring:
    gs = GridSearchCV(pipe, params, cv=5, scoring=score)
    gs.fit(text, goal)
```

Comment: This leads to running it twice (so if I want to do 5 scoring params, I would have to do it 5 times. Documentation/example suggest it should be able in one run. Link: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#using-multiple-metric-evaluation

Comment: Grid Search is meant to find the most appropriate hyperparameters for your training. If you want to try several scores, GS is probably not what you are looking for. You have several available metrics in sklearn.metrics, it might be what you need.

Comment: But GS documentation and example show it should be possible. "For evaluating multiple metrics, either give a list of (unique) strings or a dict with names as keys and callables as values." So I think GS is what I am looking for.